# How to hide ScrollBar arrows in C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, scrollbar

I would like to use a ScrollBar in my app but I don't want the default end-arrows showing up; I want to be able to use other "external" controls for activating the scroll bar.  Any ideas?

Comment: @DanBarzilay that depends. If he is using WPF, he should change the *control template*; in windows forms, a custom control is probably the only sensible way.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't - scrollbar arrows are an essential accessibility feature when a document is too long to scroll by dragging the scrollbar and when a user lacks a mousewheel or the means to use it, then the only way to scroll is by clicking on the arrow buttons.

(Apple gets away with it because all of their modern hardware supports touch-scrolling, but us on the Windows camp don't have that luxury)

Comment: I am planning to handle the scrolling my own way, hence my mentioning of "external" controls.